# Multiple integrals where the number of integrals is aribtrary

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I know that I can do, say, a triple integral such as
$$\int_{a_x}^{b_x}\int_{a_y}^{b_y}\int_{a_z}^{b_z}f(x,y,z)\,dz\,dy\,dx$$
with the input
`Integrate[f[x,y,z],{x,ax,bx},{y,ay,by},{z,az,bz}]`.

---

Now, however, I would like to do a multiple integral of the form
$$\int_{a_1}^{b_1}\cdots\int_{a_n}^{b_n}f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\,dx_n\,\ldots\,dx_1$$
for some $n$ that I specify. Is there a concise functional way to input this into Mathematica, or is the only way to manually type the full `Integrate[f[x1,...,xn],{x1,a1,b1},...,{xn,an,bn}]`. command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
multi[f_, x_, a_, b_, n_] := 
 Inactive@Integrate @@ {f @@ Array[x[#] &, {n}]}~Join~Array[{x[#], a[#], b[#]} &, {n}]
```

I used Inactive because I don't know if the purpose is purely typesetting, or if you want it to try to evaluate (if so remove it, or use Activate later).

```
multi[g, y, ymin, ymax, 10]
(* Inactive[Integrate][
 g[y[1], y[2], y[3], y[4], y[5], y[6], y[7], y[8], y[9], 
  y[10]], {y[1], ymin[1], ymax[1]}, {y[2], ymin[2], ymax[2]}, {y[3], 
  ymin[3], ymax[3]}, {y[4], ymin[4], ymax[4]}, {y[5], ymin[5], 
  ymax[5]}, {y[6], ymin[6], ymax[6]}, {y[7], ymin[7], ymax[7]}, {y[8],
   ymin[8], ymax[8]}, {y[9], ymin[9], ymax[9]}, {y[10], ymin[10], 
  ymax[10]}] *)
```

perhaps a screenshot here is better:

[image]

If its just for typesetting then you can swap subscripts into it as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using `Sequence` and `Transpose` to splice in the integration parameters:

```
mi[f_, x_, a_, b_]:=Integrate[f @@ x, Sequence @@ Transpose@{x, a, b}];
```

Usage (exemplary):

```
f[v_,w_,y_]:=v^2+w^2+y^2
x={x1,x2,x3}; a={a1,a2,a3}; b={b1,b2,b3};

mi[f,x,a,b]
(* -(1/3)(a1-b1)(a2-b2)(a3-b3)(a1^2+a2^2+a3^2+a1 b1+b1^2+a2 b2+b2^2+a3 b3+b3^2) *)
```

Comment: Alternatively, `Integrate[f @@ x, ##] & @@ Transpose[{x, a, b}]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will be complete enough for you, but here's a snippet of code that worked for me:

```
vars = Table[x[i], {i, 1, 7}]
Do[x[i, 0] = RandomInteger[{0, 5}], {i, 1, 7}]
Do[x[i, 1] = RandomInteger[{6, 10}], {i, 1, 7}]
Integrate[Plus @@ vars, 
 Sequence @@ Table[{x[i], x[i, 0], x[i, 1]}, {i, 1, 7}]]
```

In this case I create a list of variables `x[i]` (`vars`), and create a list of lower and upper integration bounds for each variable (`x[i,0]` and `x[i,1]`). The function in my toy example `f[...x[i]...]` is simply the sum of its arguments, hence `Plus@@vars` evaluates to `x[1] + ... + x[n]`. I create a list of lists with the integration variables `{...{x[i],x[i,0],x[i,1]}...}` and by applying `Sequence @@` the outer brackets are removed.