# NIntegrating in $n$ dimensions?

Tags: core-language

I need to make a function that takes a function $f$ and a natural number $n$ and returns the integration from -inf to inf in all the $n$ dimensions of $f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$. With Integrate I would do something like

```
Integrate[
    f[Sequence@@Table[x[i],{i,n}]],
    Sequence@@Table[{x[i],-Infinity,Infinity},{i,n}]
```

But with NIntegrate it throws an error. How can I do that?

Comment: Try maybe `Fold` applied to 1d integrations.

Comment: @yarchik It says that the integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values if $n\geq 1$.

Comment: @yarchik "Try maybe `Fold` applied to 1d integrations" -- interesting but not a good idea. Multi-dimensional integrals are better done using multi-dimensional integration rules and strategies. Using `Apply` over a list of arguments is better.

Comment: Maybe related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78277/multiple-integrals-where-the-number-of-integrals-is-aribtrary

Comment: @AntonAntonov Isn't it that multiple integrals with `Integrate` are automatically transformed into a multi-dimentsional integral? And `N` in front enforces numerical integration?

Comment: @yarchik I commented on `NIntegrate`'s direct use (since that is the focus of the question.)

Comment: @AntonAntonov Fair enough!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
NIntegrate[f[x], x \[Element] FullRegion[5]]
```

Note that `f` must take a list-argument, i.e. `f[{x,y,z}]` and not `f[x,y,z]`.

If you want to use explicit variable for each dimension, inject the parts of the final expression using `With`.

```
With[{vars = x /@ Range[3], int = Sequence @@ Table[{x[i], -Infinity, Infinity}, {i, 3}]},
  NIntegrate[f[vars], int]
]
```

Comment: If I create f[{x_,y_}]:=Exp[-x^2-y^2] and do NIntegrate[f[v],v\[Element] FullRegion[2]] (which should return what I want), it says that *"the numbers of variables 1 should match the region embedding dimension 2"*.

Comment: @Garmekain You probably did not clear any previous definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Apply` over the list of the arguments works:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x__] := Exp[-Total[{x}^2]];

Block[{n = 4},
 Integrate[f[Sequence @@ Table[x[i], {i, n}]], 
  Sequence @@ Table[{x[i], -Infinity, Infinity}, {i, n}]]
]

(* Pi^2 *)

Block[{n = 4},
 NIntegrate @@ {f[Sequence @@ Table[x[i], {i, n}]], 
   Sequence @@ Table[{x[i], -Infinity, Infinity}, {i, n}]}
 ]

(* 9.8696 *)
```