# Evaluating multiple integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to evaluate many long but easy multiple integrals of the form

$$ \int^{\tau}_{s_n=0}\int^{s_n}_{s_{n-1}=0}\dots\int^{s_2}_{s_1=0} C(s_1,\dots,s_n)\ ds_1\dots ds_n $$

where there are multiple integrals over some well behaving function $C$. 
Here is an example of a simple $n=3$ one:

$$ \int^{\tau}_{s_3=0}\int^{s_3}_{s_2=0}\int^{s_2}_{s_1=0}\frac{1}{2\theta}e^{-(s_1+s_3)/\theta}ds_1ds_2ds_3. $$

The symbol $\theta$ is a constant. I've calculated this particular integral by hand, and found it to be equal to

$$ \frac{\theta}{4}\Big(\theta-\theta e^{-2\tau/\theta}-2\tau e^{-\tau/\theta}\Big). $$

I can use the Mathematica `Integrate` function to check this

`Integrate[(1/(2*\[Theta]))*E^(-(s[1]+s[3])/\[Theta]),{s[3],0,\[Tau]},{s[2],0,s[3]},{s[1],0,s[2]}]`

which returns my original answer. However I want to be able to evaluate these integrals for higher $n$ and different functions $C$, and I have many of these integrals I need to calculate.

Using [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78302/62229) as a starting point, I managed to make a start at generalising the calculations

```
multi[f_, x_, t_, n_] := 
 Integrate @@ {f @@ Array[x[#] &, {n}]} ~ Join ~ Array[{x[n - # + 1], 0, If[# == 1, t, x[n - # + 2]]} &, {n}]
```

however when I try to reproduce the above example on the function

```
h[s] = (1/(2θ)) E^(-(s[1] + s[3])/θ)
```

the only answer I receive is a formatted version of my input:

[image]

My question is: How do I get Mathematica to evaluate this integral and return the same answer as my first attempt? I'm a relatively new user of Mathematica, so please forgive me if this is a trivial question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command (where I have used $t$ for $\theta$ and $a$ for $\tau$)

```
Fold[Integrate[#1, {#2[[1]], 0, #2[[2]]}] &, Exp[-(s1 + s3)/t]/(2 t),
     Partition[{s1, s2, s3, a}, 2, 1]]
```

evaluates the exact interval you have provided as an example.  Note that the result I get is $$\frac{1}{4} \theta \left(\theta - \theta e^{-2 \tau/\theta} - 2 \tau e^{-\tau / \theta}  \right)$$ which differs from your answer in that the last term has $e^{-\tau/\theta}$ rather than $e^{-\tau \theta}$.

The command does generalize readily, assuming that the lower limit of integration is always $0$ and the upper limit is the variable of integration for the next iterated integral.  For example:

```
F[n_, g_] := Fold[Integrate[#1, {#2[[1]], 0, #2[[2]]}] &, g,
                  Partition[Append[Table[s[k], {k, 1, n}], a], 2, 1]]
```

which can be used to evaluate `F[5, Exp[-s[1] + s[2] - 5 s[5]]/t s[4]]` which is $$\int_{s_5 = 0}^\tau \int_{s_4 = 0}^{s_5} \int_{s_3 = 0}^{s_4} \int_{s_2 = 0}^{s_3} \int_{s_1 = 0}^{s_2} \frac{s_5}{\theta} e^{-s_1 + s_2 - 5s_5} \, ds_1 \, ds_2 \, ds_3 \, ds_4 \, ds_5.$$

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. This works great, I guess the fold function was the more appropriate choice for this problem. The $e^{\tau/\theta}$ discrepancy is a typo on my part, I will correct it.

Comment: @WilliamMorris I should point out that `Fold` is not even necessary, since `Integrate[]` handles multiple integrals directly; e.g., `Integrate[Exp[-(s[1] + s[3])/t]/(2 t), Sequence @@ Reverse[Insert[#, 0, 2] & /@ Partition[Append[Table[s[k], {k, 1, 3}], a], 2, 1]]]` also works.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `Fold[]` method in heropup's answer, which does multiple univariate integrals, you can directly construct a multivariate integral this way:

```
Inactive[Integrate][Exp[-(s[1] + s[3])/θ]/(2 θ), ##] & @@
Prepend[Table[{s[k - 1], 0, s[k]}, {k, 3, 2, -1}], {s[3], 0, τ}]
```

$$\int_0^\tau \int_0^{s[3]} \int_0^{s[2]} \frac{e^\frac{-s[1]-s[3]}{\theta}}{2\theta} \mathrm ds[1]\mathrm ds[2]\mathrm ds[3]$$

where I used `Inactive[]` so you could visually inspect the integral produced. To evaluate, just use `Activate[]`:

```
Activate[%]
   1/4 θ (θ - E^(-((2 τ)/θ)) θ - 2 E^(-(τ/θ)) τ)
```

In general, you can use a construction like `Integrate[f, ##] & @@ Prepend[Table[{s[k - 1], 0, s[k]}, {k, n, 2, -1}], {s[n], 0, τ}]`, minding the order of arguments used by `Integrate[]`.